# SharePoint 2013 compatibility issue on IE11

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, iframe, ie-11

I have setup the SharePoint site to open in an iframe within a CRM portal.

When I try to upload a document and fill out the metadata, it gives an error that

```
'Field can't be blank' even though I have filled it out.
```

It only happens in `iframe-IE11`. It works fine in `IE10/chrome/Mozilla`. It works fine if I open the SharePoint site directly in `IE11 browser` (outside iFrame).

How do I fix it in `iframe-IE11`?

Comment: Is IE11 running in Compatibility View mode? This is required for SharePoint 2010/2013.

Comment: I tried compatibility mode, trusted sites as well but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me:

```
if (typeof browseris !== 'undefined') {
    browseris.ie = false;
}
```

The problem is in SharePoint 2013’s `init.js` file. The script calls attachEvent if it detects the browser to be IE.

I used the above code to override the property so browseris.ie never evaluates to true and attachEvent is never called. 
Find the original post [here](https://grantdotlocal.com/?p=2461)